# Using string as variable in iPython interactive

Tags: string, variables, ipython, interactive

I would like to run the following in iPython:

```
mylist = ['a','b']
def f(a,b):
    do_something

sliderinterval=(0,10,1)
w = interactive(f, a = sliderinterval, b = sliderinterval)
```

but instead of writing a and b, I would like to take them from mylist. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dict comprehension, and then pass the dictionary to the function by unpacking (`**`) in as keywords arguments.

```
mylist = ['a','b']
def f(a,b):
    print(a,b)

sliderinterval=(0,10,1)
d = {k:sliderinterval for k in mylist}
w = interactive(f, **d)
```

`**d` is equivalent to writing manually `key1=value1, key2=value2`... you will often see it in function signature as `**kwargs` or `**kw`, for unpacking list you will need only one star and see to as `*args`.